# Custom captions on the diagram with ggplot

Tags: r

I have recently started studying R. Help to make custom signatures on the diagram, as in the second picture.

```
library(tidyverse) 

data <- data.frame(
  quarter=c("Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q3", "Q3", "Q3"),
  product=c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"),
  profit=c(10, 12, 13, 10, 12, 13, 10, 12, 0)
)

p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = quarter, y = profit, fill = product)) +
  geom_col(position = 'fill') 
p
```

Fig. 1.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1OsT.png
Fig. 2.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMr0i.png

Comment: Have you read ggplot? Use help and write ggplot.. You will find how to solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

First, let's make the sum of the profit variable, which will appear above the bars:

```
library(dplyr)
totals <- data %>% group_by(quarter) %>% summarize(total = sum(profit))
```

Then the plot:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = quarter, y = profit, fill = product)) + geom_bar(stat='identity',position = 'fill') +
  geom_text(aes(label = profit),position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5)) +
  geom_text(data=totals,aes(quarter,total/100,label = total,fill = NULL),position = position_fill(vjust = 1.02))
```

Output:
[image]

*Note: I changed the values of the profit variable to correspond to the values in Fig. 2.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use geom_text(label = profit, vjust = -0.5).

```
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = quarter, y = profit, fill = product)) +
  geom_text(label = profit, vjust = -0,5)+
  geom_col(position = 'fill')
```

The vjust argument dictates the vertical alignment of where the text will be. You can modify that depending on what looks best for your figure. You can also modify the horizontal alignment with hjust = x.